# Cut CSS inheritance

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to break the CSS inheritance chain and have a default CSS again inside some container, e.g. `div` element?

This would be useful to preview abitrary HTML inside a page without having to use a `iframe` with the usual caveats (eg. not able to adapt size, needs content to be provided by another URL)

Comment: did you try "!important"?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no way to use CSS to break the inheritance chain and reset properties to browser defaults for an arbitrary element.

The [`all: default`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#all-shorthand) shorthand declaration in the new Cascading and Inheritance module will allow for this exact functionality, but first we need some implementations which as of early 2013 don't exist yet.